# Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{x -2}{8 - x^3} $ exists using the delta-epsilon definition of a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \ \cfrac{x -2}{8 - x^3} $ exists using the delta-epsilon definition of a limit.

I've tried it all. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
@Dr. Sonnhard answered the question too well. This was only meant as proxy question, asking how one solves for the limit of a rational function when the numerator and denominator both have 'zero' limits. Often a little factorization will get you through, as Dr. Sonnhard has shown. But in fact my real question is how to evaluate

$\lim_ \limits{x \to 2} \  \cfrac{1}{2 -x} - \cfrac{12}{8 - x^3} = \lim_\limits{x \to 2} \ \cfrac{(2+x)^2 + 2x - 12}{8 - x^3}$

and as far as I can tell can't be factorized any further.

Comment: The title does not match with the body. Please clarify.

Comment: @Klaus I've fixed it.

Comment: "But in fact my real question is how to evaluate"  Why would you *want* to?  You just want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that if $0< |x-2| < \delta$ it will follow that $|\frac {1}{x^2 + 2x + 4}+\frac 1{12} |<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always advise to replace $x\to x_0$ by $x=x_0+u$ with $u\to 0$ when $x_0\neq 0$.

This seems obvious, but for people having difficulties, it is simpler to think with a quantity $u$ that is going to zero, which is "small".

So here, let set $x=2+u$ and calculate $$f(x)=f(2+u)=\dfrac{u}{8-(2+u)^3}=\dfrac{u}{-12u-6u^2-u^3}=\dfrac{-1}{\underbrace{12+6u+u^2}_{\to 12}}\to -\dfrac{1}{12}$$

The limit is easier to see this way, since $6u\to 0$ and $u^2\to 0$.

Now for the epsilon-delta proof calculate $|f(x)+\frac 1{12}|=\frac 1{12}\left|\dfrac{6u+u^2}{12+6u+u^2}\right|$

Let suppose $|u|<\delta$ and also $\delta<1$ then $|u|^2<|u|$

Thus the numerator $|6u+u^2|\le 6|u|+|u|^2\le 6|u|+|u|\le 7|u|\le 7\delta$

For the denominator we proceed the same way

$|12+6u+u^2|\ge |12-|6u+u^2||\ge|12-7\delta|\ge|12-7|\ge 5$

Finally gathering all together, $$\left|f(x)+\frac 1{12}\right|\le \frac 1{12}\times\frac{7\delta}5\le\frac{7}{60}\delta\le\delta$$

Take $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$\frac{x-2}{8-x^3}=-\frac{1}{4+2x+x^2}$$
It is $$\frac{1}{2-x}-\frac{12}{8-x^3}=\frac{8-x^3-12(2-x)}{(2-x)(8-x^3)}$$
This simplifies to $$-\frac{4+x}{4+2x+x^2}$$

Comment: Could you please see my edit?